# Typescript parse string into groups of digits as 345-67 and text with both words and digits

Tags: javascript, typescript, split

My string is in format "[111-11] text here with digits 111, [222-22-22]; 333-33 text here" and I want to parse so that I have the code [111-11], [222-22-22], [333-33] and its corresponding text. 
I don't have fixed splitter except for the code xxx-xx or xxx-xx-xx.

I tried in this way but it fails to get digits at desc part. \D will get anything but digits.

```
let text = "[111-11] text here with digits 111, [222-22-22]; 333-33 text here";
let codes=[];
let result = text.replace(/(\d{3}(-\d{2})+)(\D*)/g,(str, code, c, desc) =>  {      
        desc = desc.trim().replace(/[\[\]']+/g,'');   
       if (code) codes.push({'code':code.trim(),'desc': desc});
        return str;
    }); //parse and split codes
```

Finally, I want result in this style:

```
[{code:'111-11', desc:'text here with digits 111'},
{code:'222-22-22', desc:''},
{code:'333-33', desc:'text here'}]
```

I really appreciate the help.

Comment: what do you mean with "*and its corresponding text*". please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: Thanks Nina for helping. By corresponding text, I mean the text till next code format or end of string.

Comment: why is in the second case desc empty and not a semicolon? is comma or semicolon a separator?

Comment: Comma and semicolon are not always separator. They can be part of desc text too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a search for the brackets values and the following text in groups and a positive lookahead for the bracket part or end of string. Then destructuring the string and push the wanted object.

```js
const regex = /\[?(\d{3}(-\d\d)+)\]?(.*?)(?=\[?\d{3}(-\d\d)+\]?|$)/gm;
const str = `[111-11] text here with digits 111, [222-22-22]; 333-33 text here`;
var m,
    code, desc,
    result= [];

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }        
    ({ 1: code, 3: desc } = m);
    result.push({ code, desc })
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you Nina. Really helps. I didn't think of look ahead and in my tries exec loop would always go in infinte loop... Thank you. This really really helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
const Sep = ','
const PatSep = /[,;]/g
// skippng first spaces, then getting the numbers (and ignoring the brackets
// if presents), then gets rest
const PatPart = /^\s*\[?(\d{3}(-\d{2})+)]?(.*)$/


const src =
  "[111-11] text here with digits 111, [222-22-22]; 333-33 text here"

const parse = src => {
  // to avoir differents terminations
  const normalized = src.replace (PatSep, Sep)

  return normalized.split (Sep).reduce((acc, part) => {
    // getting code and desc from part
    const [_, code, __, desc] = part.match (PatPart)

    // accumulating in desired array
    return [
      ...acc,
      {code, desc}
    ]
  }, [])
}

console.log(parse (src))
```

;)

Comment: Thank you zedryas. It is a good approach. As I was trying to simplify the problem statement here, I didn't mention that comma and semicolon can be part of the description text so to use that as first splitter would not work in my case.